# How can I let a user input their info?

Tags: java

Is it possible to let a user input their first, middle initial, and last name in one method and then return all the fields?

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class name {
        // firstName middleInitial and lastName
        // toUpperCase for names

    String firstName, midddleInitial, lastName;

    public name(String firstName, String middleInitial, String lastName) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter First Name:");
        String firstName = scanner.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Enter Middle Initial:");


        System.out.println("Enter Last Name:");

        return firstName;
        return middleInital;
        return lastName;
    }
} // end of name class
```

Comment: ask yourself 2 questions. "How is  first name being entered by the user and stored?". Then ask yourself, "If i can print out things in quotes, how can i print out names?". `return` is not the answer

Comment: Why would you want to return anything from constructor? Its purpose is to initialize your instance. One problem with your code is that you are assigning user input to *local* variable `String firstName = ...` instead of `firstName = ...` (or to be more verbose `this.firstName = ...`).

Answer (score 1):

You can only return one thing from a method.  But you COULD do something like this:

```
String firstName, midddleInitial, lastName;

public void inputName() {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter First Name:");
    firstName = scanner.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Enter Middle Initial:");
    midddleInitial = scanner.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Enter Last Name:");
    lastName = scanner.nextLine();
}
```

The method returns nothing.  But, the names will now be in the class-level variables, which are accessible throughout the class.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like below, call the method iteratively to get your answer. Let me know what are you trying to achieve by your code, so I could tune it accordingly. 
You could try doing it recursively to get it in your method itself, which is what you're trying to achieve, I presume.

```
static String firstName;
static String middleInitial;
static String lastName;

private static int i;


public static String name() {
    System.out.print("i"+i);
    if(i==1)
    {Scanner scanner =new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter First Name:");
    firstName = scanner.nextLine();
    return firstName;
    }
    else if(i==2)
    {
        Scanner scanner =new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter Middle Name:");
        middleInitial = scanner.nextLine();
        return middleInitial;
    }
    else
    {
        Scanner scanner =new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter Last Name:");
        lastName = scanner.nextLine();
        return lastName;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    i=1;
    if(i==1)
    {
        String name1=name();
        System.out.print("1"+name1);
        i=2;
    }
    if(i==2)
    {
        String name2=name();
        System.out.print("2"+name2);
        i=3;
    }
    if(i==3)
    {
        String name3=name();
        System.out.print("3"+name3);
    }
}
```